# Firefox buffering custom mouse

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

When running this snippet in Firefox the mouse is **very** buffered is there a way to fix it?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-1 -1 2 2' width='10' height='10'><circle r='1'/></svg>"), auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue on Firefox. What do you mean by "buffered"?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz https://youtu.be/Udi42GxxfBQ